# How to write test with watir for testing status post on facebook

Tags: ruby, watir

How can i write a ruby.rb script using watir, that will write a string to the status and then post it. so far i have identified the status form and have been abot to click the post button, but i cant get the text in the status to update programmatically with watir. i have identified the  that holds the text but it seems as though the span is updated with some java via a data-text attribute. this is just a guess so it might not actually be the case.

Comment: Please show your current code, what you are expecting, and what the actual result is. What version of ruby, watir, platform???

Answer (score 0):

Until you update your question with what code you've tried I can give you this idea. If you can get the cursor to show up in the text field you can do:

```
browser.send_keys 'x'
browser.send_keys :enter
```

This works for me in Ruby 2.4 with Watir controlling Safari on a Mac.

Comment: I definitely tried all the basic ways like what you posted,  but I was on chrome maybe I'll have better luck with safari. I'll post more code if safari doesn't work  out.

Answer (score 0):

Last I looked, automated/scripted responses to postings  on Facebook was disallowed by facebook’s terms of service. (2nd item in third section ‘safety’).

So step 1 is to be employed or otherwise authorized by Facebook to access their site using automation.  Eg sign up as a partner developer.

Unless you are specifically testing their site, the way to do automation on their platform is via their API, not via driving a browser.

If this is for a class, print out the Facebook terms of service, hilight the appropriate section and ask your professor for an assignment that would not get you banned from Facebook.

Given current events, most of us do not want to assist with anything remotely resembling creation or upkeep of a ‘bot’ that posts or responds to social media, which is pretty much what you are asking.

Comment: Okay , I see the issue there, I read somewhere on SO, that posting automation was okay, guess not. Either way this has got me curious as to what clever mechanism fb is using to make this difficult for a beginner coder like my self. Guess I'll have to look into some REACT.

Comment: Posting automation questions for your own site, or to me you have rights to automate against us just fine.  Asking how to do automation against a site where the Terms of Service prohibit bots is a different thing.  Something that sounds like a social media bot or data scraper is another magnitude of difference.